# object oriented form validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I created this form validation script, where a "valid" object holds properties with boolean values. First, the code loops through every required element in the form and performs two types of generic checks. 1. Does the element have the required attribute? If so, does it have a value? 2. Does the value match with the type attribute? E.g., Does an email input hold an email address? Once the generic checks have been performed, the script then makes some checks that apply to individual elements on the form.

TRACKING VALID ELEMENTS To keep track of errors, an object called va1id is created.As the code loops through each element performing the generic checks, a property is added to the va1id object for each element: • The property name is the value of its id attribute. • The value is a Boolean. Whenever an error is found on an element, this value is set to fa1se.

The problem i encounter here is that the form submits the inputs even though the email input does not match an email type, every other thing works fine. why is this so and what do i do to rectify this bug.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>

                <form action="new_facebook.html" method="get" class="form2" novalidate>

                    <span id = "surnameError" class = "hidden">what is your first name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder= "first name"  class="sign_up all names" id = "first_name" required/>

                    <span id = "surnameError" class = "hidden">what is your surname</span>
                    <input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname"  class="sign_up all names" id = "surname" required/><br/>


                    <span id = "emailError" class = "hidden">email address</span>
                    <input type="email" name="mobile_number_or_email_address" placeholder="email address"  class="sign_up2 all" id= "mobile_number_or_email_address" class = "hidden" required /><br/>

                    <span id = "passwordError" class = "hidden">password</span>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="new password"  class="sign_up2 all" id = "password" required />
                    <br/><br/>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account" id="submit"/>

                </form>

        <script src = "jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.form2').on('submit' , function(e){

                    var valid = {};
                    var isValid;
                    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('all');


                    var validateType = {
                        email: function(el){
                            var emailPattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

                            return emailPattern.test(el.value);
                        }
                    }


                    function validateRequired(el){
                            if(el.required){  // if the element is required
                                return el.value;
                            }else{ // if the element is not required
                                return true;
                            }
                    }

                    function validateTypes(el){
                        var type = el.getAttribute('type');

                        if(validateType[type] === 'function'){
                            return validateType[type](el);
                        }else{ // no need to validate 
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    for(var i = 0; i<elements.length ; i++){
                        isValid = validateRequired(elements[i]) && validateTypes(elements[i]);
                        valid[elements[i].id] = isValid;

                        if(!isValid){
                            elements[i].style.border = '1px solid red';
                        }else{
                            elements[i].style.border = '';
                        }
                    }

                    for(var property in valid){

                        if(!valid[property]){
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }

                });

            }); // end of document ready
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

validateType[type] returns the actual function, so to check the type instead of

```
if(validateType[type] === 'function')
```

use

```
if(typeof validateType[type] === 'function')
```

```js
$('.form2').on('submit' , function(e){

                    var valid = {};
                    var isValid;
                    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('all');


                    var validateType = {
                        email: function(el){
                            var emailPattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                            return emailPattern.test(el.value);
                        }
                    }


                    function validateRequired(el){
                            if(el.required){  // if the element is required
                                return el.value;
                            }else{ // if the element is not required
                                return true;
                            }
                    }

                    function validateTypes(el){
                        var type = el.getAttribute('type');
                        if(typeof validateType[type] === 'function'){
                            return validateType[type](el);
                        }else{ // no need to validate 
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    for(var i = 0; i<elements.length ; i++){
                        isValid = validateRequired(elements[i]) && validateTypes(elements[i]);
                        valid[elements[i].id] = isValid;

                        if(!isValid){
                            elements[i].style.border = '1px solid red';
                        }else{
                            elements[i].style.border = '';
                        }
                    }

                    for(var property in valid){

                        if(!valid[property]){
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="new_facebook.html" method="get" class="form2" novalidate>

                    <span id = "surnameError" class = "hidden">what is your first name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder= "first name"  class="sign_up all names" id = "first_name" required/>

                    <span id = "surnameError" class = "hidden">what is your surname</span>
                    <input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname"  class="sign_up all names" id = "surname" required/><br/>


                    <span id = "emailError" class = "hidden">email address</span>
                    <input type="email" name="mobile_number_or_email_address" placeholder="email address"  class="sign_up2 all" id= "mobile_number_or_email_address" class = "hidden" required /><br/>

                    <span id = "passwordError" class = "hidden">password</span>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="new password"  class="sign_up2 all" id = "password" required />
                    <br/><br/>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account" id="submit"/>

                </form>
```